# Angular2 - how to install ng2-google-place-autocomplete package using npm

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install, node-modules

I am trying to install this package:
https://github.com/psykolm22/ng2-google-place-autocomplete

I followed the instructions in the README file, but I got following Console error:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/ng2-google-place-autocomplete 404 (Not Found)
```

When I occasionally install via npm, a tree of package files is showed after the install command.
However this time, nothing is showed except this:

```
`-- ng2-google-place-autocomplete@1.4.2
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

So, I doubt that the package is not successfully installed, even though it's folder exists inside the node_modules..

I don't know if I have to manually configure systemjs.config.js, since the package doesn't seem to be there in any map field.

Does anyone know what's going wrong?

Comment: did you configure in your systemjs?

Comment: do I have to manually configure it? in the how to install section they didn't mention this step..

Anyway, I noticed that all maps inside this file are to files with extension: .umd.js

Any there is no file inside the package folder that ends with this extension

Answer (score 0):

Include the below line into your systemjs

```
'ng2-google-place-autocomplete' : 'npm:ng2-google-place-autocomplete\src\index.js'
```

Comment: these are the files inside src folder (no index.js):
404.html
<DIR>          app
<DIR>          assets
<DIR>          environments
favicon.ico
index.html
index.ts
polyfills.ts
styles.css
test.ts
tsconfig.json

Comment: did you include the script reference into your index.html as per the documentation?

Comment: Yes, of course.
I am pretty sure that the problem is with the package being downloaded but never installed.. I wonder how can we manually install it since there is not js file, do i transpile it into js and then link to it inside the systemjs? may this be the solution?

Comment: are you available in teamviewer?

Comment: 10 minutes please